# How do you create a full page backgroud image using Adobe flash

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

Create a full page background image slideshow like http://beyondfayte.com/ and http://hmxmedia.com/ using Flash?
I'm new to flash and I want to know hoe to create these full screen image slideshows, that start on page load and scale proportionally just like the above two websites, using Flash CS5 AS3.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your_styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <object>
            <embed src="your_flash.swf" />
        </object>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
html,
body
{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}

body{ overflow: hidden; }

object,
embed
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

AS3:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;

    public class Document extends Sprite
    {
        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function Document()
        {
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I keep getting error msgs like "1083:syntax error:package is unexpected"

Comment: This code goes into an external .as file and then selected as the document class for the .fla file. It does not go onto the timeline.

Answer (score 1):

You need to the flash width and height to 100% in the HTML tags, and listen to the Event.RESIZE handler to manually scale and move around the content as you want (use stage.stageWidth / stage.stageHeight to get the new size).

You also need to set the scaleMode to something useful, eg: `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;`